# warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]

Tags: c, pointers, warnings

I have created a vector (vectorR) of ints using shared memory in Linux, the code is as follows:

```
    int shmidR, tamR;
    tamR = fil*col2;
    int *vectorR[tamR]; // Creating the vector
    shmidR = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int)*fil*col2, IPC_CREAT|0666);
    vectorR[tamR] = (int*) shmat(shmidR, NULL, 0);
```

Then I operate on this vector and at the end i want to print the contents to see if it is good:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tamR; i++)
{
    printf("%i", vectorR[i]);
}
```

But i get the warning in the Title: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]

Comment: And what is unclear with the warning? The warning uses the human language specially for you.

Comment: `int *vectorR[tamR];` is an array of pointers.

Comment: ... and `vectorR` having been declared that way, `vectorR[tamR] = (int*) shmat(shmidR, NULL, 0)` overruns the bounds of `vectorR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int *vectorR[tamR]` creates a array of int pointers. What you want is an array of integers. Just use `int vectorR[tamR]`.

```
int shmidR, tamR;
tamR = fil*col2;
int vectorR[tamR]; // Creating the vector
shmidR = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int)*fil*col2, IPC_CREAT|0666);
vectorR[tamR] = (int) shmat(shmidR, NULL, 0);
```